# Aggregations for categories, sorted by category sequence

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have an elastic index, in which each document contains the following:

```
category {
"id": 4,
"name": "Green",
"seq": 2
}
```

I can use aggregations to get me the doc count for each of the categories:

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "aggs": {
  "category": {
   "terms": {
    "field": "category.name"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

This is fine, but the aggs are sorted by the doc count. What I'd like is to have the buckets sorted by the *seq* value, something that's easy in SQL.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ordering terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order).

Something like this could work, but only if `"name"` and `"sequence"` have the right relationships (one-to-one, or it works out in some other way):

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "category": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "category.name",
            "order" : { "seq_num" : "asc" }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "seq_num": {
               "max": {
                  "field": "category.seq"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used for testing:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4e551b2faec81eb0343e0e6d0cc9b10f20d7d4c1

Comment: Thank you! I discovered something useful, too: if the category.seq field is analyzed (not marked as not_analyzed) then it doesn't work.